# how to stop a webpage from loading on clicking back button?

Tags: javascript

I m trying to disable a page from loading on click of back button after it is redirected to some certain pages. I have used onunload event but it stops loading of the page after visiting any page.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

function preventBack() {
    window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); 
window.onunload = function() {
    null
};

</script>
```

Also suggest if i could use window.stop(); Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the page it comes from isn’t your page, you can’t do anything about that. All timeouts/JavaScript will be cleared when your page is unloaded, and `null` inside a handler does absolutely nothing.

This is a user-friendliness thing that browsers do, because not being able to go back would be horrible. Please rethink your approach.

Comment: i want it for a page created by me only. Can u suggest something?

Comment: @Ani: Can you explain why you need this behaviour?

Comment: i am creating a transaction system in which after commiting transaction it shouldn't go to the previous page. Also after login it shouldn't go back to login page. can u help?

Comment: You could build your entire system using the HTML5 History API, which allows you to control each part using JavaScript. The usual way, though, is to keep the current “committed” step in your session and display an error if someone tries to go back and resubmit. People expect this now (more if you say so) and it’s not generally worth getting around…